# Magento 1.9 patch error

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, magento-1.9.2.1, supee-10888

I trying to patch 1.9.2.1 from supee-752 to supee-10888 and getting next error:
[image]

[image]
Cant find the any solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Download it again from another browser.